# php pagination with date and not serial number

Tags: php, pagination

I have database with 80 rows currently and it increases day by day as i am conducting online lectures for doctors on every tuesday and saturday. For Members of my site, recording of these lectures are available.

My database contains columns like lecture_start_date, lecture_end_date, display_time (+45 minutes to lecture end date-time)...

currently 80 lectures recording links are available on single page. so i created pagination for 10 lectures each. code is as follows..

```
     $sql = "SELECT COUNT(lecture_start) FROM es_lecture_master"; 
     $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
     $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
     $total_records = $row[0]; 
     $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10); 

     for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

                echo "<button><a class=\"page\" href='lec_history_p.php?page=".$i."'>".$i." </a></button>"; 
     };
```

And

```
     $current_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
     $start_from = ($page-1) * 10; 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM es_lecture_master where display_time <'".$current_date."' ORDER BY `lecture_start` DESC limit $start_from, 10"; 
     $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);  
     $ss=mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
     $counts= sizeof($arrayreversed);

     while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {


     <div align="left">Lecture No :<div class="numberCircle" style="display:inline;"> <? echo $ss;?></div></div>
          <table width="80%" style="text-align:left;" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="4"  cellpadding="4" class="tabl">
     <tr>
         <td width="32%">E-Sambhasha Subject : </td>
         <td ><?=stripslashes($data["lecture_subject"])?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td width="32%">Lecturer :</td>
         <td><?=$data["lecturer_name"]?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td width="32%">IST Day & Date :</td>
         <td><?=date("l ",strtotime($data['lecture_start']))?>,<?=date("d M Y",strtotime($data['lecture_start']));?> 
          </td>
       </tr>
         <tr>
         <td width="32%" style="background-color:#d44302; color:#f4f4af;">IST Timing :</td>
         <td><?=date("h:i:s A ",strtotime($data['lecture_start']))?> - <?=date("h:i:s A ",strtotime($data['lecture_end']))?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td width="32%">Session Recording :</td>
         <td>
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"   cellpadding="0" class="tabl"><tr>
         <td width="26%">
          <button data-fancybox-href="<?php echo $data['recording_link'];?>" class="fancy fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" >Play Recording</button> </td>


      </tr></table>


         </td>
       </tr>


     </table>
     </div>
```

With This Code I am getting result as following image.

But I don't want to show serial numbers for pagination but want to show date range of lectures conducted for pagination...e.g. button with label ="From 13 March 2014 To 7 Jan 2014" (here 13 march will be lecture start date of Lecture shown on Top on page 1) instead of Button "1", button with label = "From 06 Jan 2014 To 12 October 2014" Instead of Button with label "2"?
(database contains lecture_start_date and lecture_end_date columns)

Also in Lecture No., on every page it shows Lecture No. 10 to 1..instead of that how to show like on page 1 Lecture 80 to 70, on page 2 - lecture no. 70 to 60 and so on.. ?

see image -

[image]

Comment: why don't you get the first date from the first item displayed and the last item displayed and change the page button's text?

Comment: @ Daniel Cheung , How To Do That ? Can u help me for coding ?

Comment: my suggestion, dirty trick, preload the other 9 pages and inject js every time in a while loop and update the date values into an array and work on it. then, use the processed string and change the text in the buttons

Comment: Thnx Daniel Cheung, But I am a doctor by profession and very weak in php and thess things. So please, can u Show some sample code for this ? as all code is given above, u can use data/text from it..e.g. database column names etc....plz don't take it otherwise..

Comment: sorry for that, let me use some time to think for a good enough solution

Comment: ok no problem plz take your own time and i am sure u will return with good solution for me